# SET DATEFIRST CURSOR WHILE LOOP Error - set options have changed

Tags: sql-server, date, while-loop, cursor

I am having very strange behaviour with my cursor loop here is what I got;

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE CursorTest CURSOR FOR  
SELECT ID FROM tblSomething

OPEN Schedule
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorTest INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @StartDate = StartDate FROM tblAnother WHERE ID = @ID
        SELECT @StartDate --12/06/2018
        -- NOW WE MOD IT
        SET DATEFIRST 6 -- WE START ON SATURDAY 1
        SET @StartDate = DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)
        SELECT @StartDate -- ANSWER IS 4
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorTest INTO @ID
    END

CLOSE CursorTest
DEALLOCATE CursorTest
```

Now if I run this I get to the second row on the CURSOR and it will crash and state;

```
Could not complete cursor operation because the set options have changed since the cursor was declared.
```

Now if I comment out the;

```
--SET DATEFIRST 6
```

The error goes away, so I am thinking that SET DATEFIRST is modding the database which is causing the error.

Is there away around this using something like;

```
SET @StartDate = DATEPART(dw,@StartDate,DATEFIRST 6)
```

Something along those lines.

Comment: OPEN Schedule change to OPEN CursorTest

Comment: I know that is just a typo, still get the crash...

Comment: Why are you doing this with a `cursor`?  It looks like you could achieve this with a simple set based query and a `case` expression?

Comment: I am using a cursor because I am pulling 15000 rows from one table and each row needs to go and insert 50 rows into another table. It is a big script.

Comment: 750,000 rows is not that much.  Perhaps ask another question for assistance on how to achieve that `insert` and leave this one up for anyone that needs to change the `datefirst` property within a `cursor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it;

```
SET DATEFIRST 6 -- outside CURSOR LOOP;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @StartWeek = DATEPART(wk,@StartDate) -- CORRECT BY DATEFIRST 6
        SET @StartDay = (DATEPART(dw,@StartDate) + @@DATEFIRST - 1 - 1) % 7 + 1 -- MONDAY 1
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could move `SET`:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATE
DECLARE @ID INT
DECLARE CursorTest CURSOR FOR  
SELECT ID FROM tblSomething

SET DATEFIRST 6 -- WE START ON SATURDAY 1

OPEN Schedule
FETCH NEXT FROM CursorTest INTO @ID

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @StartDate = StartDate FROM tblAnother WHERE ID = @ID
        SELECT @StartDate --12/06/2018
        -- NOW WE MOD IT

        SET @StartDate = DATEPART(dw,@StartDate)
        SELECT @StartDate -- ANSWER IS 4
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorTest INTO @ID
    END

CLOSE CursorTest
DEALLOCATE CursorTest
```